# How to retrieve data with group by aggregate function in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, group-by, aggregate-functions

I am new to SQL Server 2012. This is my table DDL & DML script.

```
CREATE TABLE [tbl_item_i18n]
(
    [item_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [lang_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [item_text] [nvarchar](max) NULL
);

INSERT INTO [tbl_item_i18n] ([item_id],[lang_id],[item_text])
VALUES (1, 1, 'item1'), (1, 2, 'idem 1'),
       (2, 1, 'item2'),
       (3, 1, 'item3'), (3, 2, 'idem 3'),
       (4, 1, 'item4'), (4, 2, 'idem 4');
```

My expected output is :

[image]

This is what I have tried :

```
select 
    lang_id,
    case when lang_id = 2 AND itemI18N.item_text is not null then itemI18N.item_text
        when lang_id = 1 then itemI18N.item_text
    end as ite_texte
from 
    tbl_item_i18n itemI18N
group by 
    itemI18N.item_id, lang_id, itemI18N.item_text
```

But it does not give me expected result.

**Purpose** :- I would like to retrieve data for `lang_id = 2`. If the record for `lang_id = 2` does not exist, then retrieve data for `lang_id = 2`.
How do I retrieve data using aggregate function?

Comment: What item_name you want? first? last? Please explain what is the logic for your desire output.

Comment: So what's the rule on which `item_name` to select for each `item_id`?

Comment: Please consider updated question. (Purpose)

Comment: I think you have your schema wrong (reverse). Because looks like `item_id ` should be first column and `lenguaje_id` should be second column?

Comment: You said "If the record for lang_id = 2 does not exist, then retrieve data for lang_id = 2.". Was one of those supposed to say lang_id= 1 - which one?

Answer (score 0):

`LEFT JOIN` Bring all the column with lenguaje 1, and null if doesnt have lenguaje 2.

I include extra column so you understand the result.

```
SELECT 
    item_id, 
    CASE 
       WHEN B.lang_id IS NULL THEN A.item_text
       ELSE B.item_text
    END as item_name,
    A.*
    B.*
FROM tbl_item_i18n A
LEFT JOIN tbl_item_i18n B
   ON A.item_id = B.item_id
  AND A.lang_id < B.lang_id
```

**NOTE**

Maybe need especial consideration if more than 2 lenguajes.

**Another solution**

```
SELECT *
FROM 
  (
    SELECT item_id, lang_id, item_text as item_name, 
            ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by item_id order by lang_id desc) as RN
   FROM tbl_item_i18n
  ) as t 
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: Is there any other way without using `left join`, because it is just a simple query. I have very very complex query. So if I use left join then there will be performance issue.

Comment: let me think about it, But shouldnt have performance issue if you have proper index for `item_id`  and `lenguaje_id` This is very simple query.

Comment: This kind of complex queries are used in reports. There are almost 25 tables in a single query. If I use left join then it will become 50 table joins. So it will down the performance of query.

Comment: I include another solution, in this case will bring you the record with the highest `leng_id`. But again if adding a JOIN affect your performance, you may have different issue there. probably need add on aditional index